# Can't create organization identifier Visual Studio mac

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community for Mac and I am trying to create a new Native App project.  I click on New Project, select Native App and then select Next and it asks me for an App Name and Organization identifier.

After adding an app name no matter what I enter for Organization Identifier, the Next button remains grayed out.  I am just trying to create a basic app and mess around with it but I can't get past this dialog.

It's probably something stupid I am doing or not doing but I don't know what to enter to allow this to proceed.

What do I need to enter to allow this to proceed?  The tooltip help isn't useful and has just made things more confusing as there seem's to be a bug in the tooltip text where it is showing html formatting characters.

Comment: Can you select a target platform? (iOS or Android). If not then you may need to install Xamarin.iOS and/or Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just uninstalled and reinstalled this and it started working.  I'm not sure why it was giving me trouble in the first place.